# How to share react native components between screens

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to share react native components between two screens, like what you can do with the [hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) library in ios. I want the component to animate between the two screens.

I have tried the fluid-transitions library, but I couldnt get it to work.

ie.

[image]

Comment: I believe you could try using constraint layout transitions.

Comment: @ivan what is constrant layout transitions? I cant find anything on the web about it.

Comment: I used those to make this animation https://imgur.com/dQcbdai if it is what you're looking for i could explain what they are.

Comment: @ivan Yeah thats exactly what i'm looking for! I would appreciate it if you point me in the right direction on how to do something like that.

Comment: In that case this should be what you need https://developer.android.com/training/transitions, however i didn't make my transition as they explained there, i made it with the use of 2 constraintLayouts. 
We should probably go to a chat to explain all of this.

Comment: I made a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197508/how-to-share-react-native-components-between-screens

Comment: @ivan sorry i dont have enough reputation to send messages in a chat room, im pretty new to stack overflow. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Ah its okay then, Ill just try to post it as an answer then and hopefully it will work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do an animation like this you can use TransitionManager, i personally usually use it with constraintLayouts.

What you need in order to do this is 2 constraintLayouts (both need to have all the elements that will appear on screen and the properties that change between layouts should only be the constraints themselves.)

With the 2 layouts you can make an animation from one to the other like this:

```
final ConstraintSet constraint1 = new ConstraintSet();
constraint1.clone(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_shrunk);

final ConstraintSet constraint2 = new ConstraintSet();
constraint2.clone(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.layout_expanded);

//The view you pass as an argument to both methods should be the layout's root.
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
constraint2.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

Result:

[image]

However this kind of animations are also possible to be made in other ways, please check the official docs for reference: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions

Note: to get the reverse animation too just apply the other constraintSet.